# Elastic Search, Boolean query on array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

The document has a field like this.

```
"device_versions": [
            {
              "name": "android",
              "min_major_ver": 3,
              "min_minor_ver": 54,
              "min_patch_ver": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "ios",
              "min_major_ver": 2,
              "min_minor_ver": 59,
              "min_patch_ver": 0
            }
          ]
```

I want to write a query like this

**(device_versions.name = 'android' AND device_versions.min_major_ver = 3 AND device_versions.min_minor_ver = 55)**

I have written the following query-

```
"must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "device_versions.name": "android"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "device_versions.min_major_ver": {
                    "from": 3,
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true,
                    "to": null
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "device_versions.min_minor_ver": {
                    "from": 55,
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true,
                    "to": null
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
```

The problem with above query is: The last range query matches with the array element which has device name = 'ios'

What I need is: Apply 3 condition on same array element. device = "android" AND min_major_ver = 55 AND min_minor_ver = 55

Comment: are u aware of nested datatype in elasticsearch? Does your mapping has nested enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Your mapping should have nested enabled, otherwise your objects will flatten out

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

will be stored as

```
{
  "group" :        "fans",
  "user.first" : [ "alice", "john" ],
  "user.last" :  [ "smith", "white" ]
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

after nesting enabled your query should be

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "device_versions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "device_versions.name": "android"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "device_versions.min_major_ver": {
                  "from": 3,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true,
                  "to": null
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "device_versions.min_minor_ver": {
                  "from": 55,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true,
                  "to": null
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```